# Removing Upload Permission in a SharePoint online Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, css, file-upload, custom-permission-level

I have a custom permission level set to only allow read in a particular document library. However, these users still are able to upload files, which is not desired! I cannot find any OOB settings to prevent this.

Is there a way I can remove the upload permission or prevent upload for a everyone except the site owners?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, according to the provided screenshot, this custom permission allows users to only read documents but not upload documents.

Please check whether users only have this custom permission in this document library.